# Usage of -n and -z in test built in - Bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, test

Consider the following in bash:

```
root@debian-lap:/tmp I=$(echo)
root@debian-lap:/tmp echo "$I"

root@debian-lap:/tmp [ -z "$I" ] && echo "TRUE" || echo "FALSE"
TRUE
```

This means that variable $I is `zero`. The same I could achieve with negation test to see if variable is non zero, and `!` makes test reverse so it checks is variable `zero`

```
root@debian-lap:/tmp ! [ -n "$I" ] && echo "TRUE" || echo "FALSE"
TRUE
root@debian-lap:/tmp
```

So, my question is, are there any special cases when to use `-z` and `! -n` , or vice versa `! -z` and `-n` as they are basically doing the same test?

Thanks

Comment: Earlier shells, like the Bourne shell, did not have a `!` reserved word for negation of expressions, so you needed both -z and -n. See [differences](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Major-Differences-From-The-Bourne-Shell.html).

Comment: Thanks guys, know its maybe dumb question, but had to ask are there some special cases of using it :)

Comment: The only dumb questions are those left unasked, and those asked twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given `-n` and `-z` for the same reason that other test suites give you both `==` and `!=`, or `AND` and `NOT`.  Some test cases can be made a lot clearer to future maintainers by eschewing double-negatives.  Also, as mentioned in an above comment, ancient incarnations of `sh` (i. e. the Bourne and Thompson shells), as opposed to modern POSIX `sh` did not have a `!` keyword to negate the truthiness of `test` expressions.

Answer (score 9):

1. `[ -z "$var" ]`
2. `[ ! -n "$var" ]`
3. `! [ -n "$var" ]`
4. `[ ! "$var" ]`
5. `[ "$var" = '' ]`
6. `[ ! "$var" != '' ]`
7. `[ '' = "$var" ]`...²

Are all functionally equivalent in POSIX shells¹. The Bourne shell¹ didn't have the `!` keyword, so wouldn't support 3 above and had all sorts of bugs with special values of `$var` (like `=`, `-n`, `!`...) in all but 7 ([many other shells also had similar bugs](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/test/)).

In a similar vein, you can (and should) use `[ "$a" = "$b" ] && [ "$x" = "$y" ]` in place of `[ "$a" = "$b" -a "$x" = "$y" ]`, the latter being deprecated and non-reliable.

The `!` of 3 is a POSIX shell feature. It still makes sense of the `test`/`[` utility to support its own `!` operator (as in 2/6) for other shells or non-shell applications that may want to use it and negate conditions.

The `test` utility was introduced by Unix v7. Before that, there was a `if` utility that had `!`, `=`, `!=`, `-a`/`-o`, but no `-n`/`-z`.

I suppose `-n`/`-z` were added for convenience (`test -n "$var"` being a short  form for `test "$var" != ''` and `-z` being added for consistency)

---

¹ Technically, while `test`/`[` is built in virtually all Bourne-like shells, that's not mandated by POSIX and early versions of the Bourne shell didn't have it built-in. While the Almquist shell always had a `test` builtin, some BSDs did not enable it so some BSDs did not have a `[`/`test` built in `sh` until the 2000s. In any case, regardless of whether a particular shell has a `[`/`test` command built-in, all POSIX systems will also have a `[`/`test` command on the file system (which may or may not behave the same as the `[`/`test` builtin command of any shell on the system).

² That's not to say that's the only commands that can be used to test if a variable is the empty string.

```
case $var in
  "") ...
esac
```

is one way that doesn't involve running any command.

```
expr "x$var" : 'x$' > /dev/null
${var:+"false"}
awk 'BEGIN{exit(ARGV[1] != "")}' "$var"
[ "${#var}" -eq 0 ]
```

Are more examples of convoluted ways to do that.

Some Korn-like shells like `bash` also have some built-in conditional and arithmetic *constructs* that aim at replacing the `[` command (`[[ -z $var ]]`, `((${#var} == 0))`...).

Comment: I've always wondered about this *"I suppose -n/-z were added for convenience (test -n "$var" being a short form for test "$var" != '' and -z being added for consistency)"* How is that convenient? It's only three characters shorter, and it's another thing to memorize. Is there nothing more to historically or now?