# What does ! mean in the statement if [ ! -n "$1" ]

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to understand what the bellow statement means.

`if [ ! -n "$1" ]`

What I understand from the rest of the statement is:
An if statement (`if`),
something I do not understand ( `!` ),
checks the length of a string is nonzero ( `-n` ),
the first argument ( `"$1"` )

Comment: when in doubt run `command --help` or `man command`. `man [` will give the the answer right away

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371138/70524 covers it thoroughly, I think

Comment: @phuclv, none of those suggestions apply here. `[ --help` returns an error; `man [`, on systems that have such a man page, would generally give you the man page of the standalone `[` utility, not of the `[` builtin of any particular shell (here for the OP: `bash`). You'd need `info bash [`

Answer (score 2):

From the [GNU Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions):

> `-n` *string*
>
> True if the length of *string* is non-zero.

and

> `!` *expr*
>
> True if *expr* is false.

So, the `!` is actually the negation operator for the test if the string `$1` is empty. It should basically be equivalent to testing

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
```